# Cisco Router IOS update

Tags: routing, router, cisco-ios, troubleshooting, networking

I am facing problem in update the IOS of Cisco 7304 router. I am upgrading from 12.4(24)T2, to 15.2(4)S7 this. but I was boot from this version 15.2(4)S7 it booted proper from flash. But when I put the command `show version` it is showing

```
YLINX-EDGE-LHE-01#sh version
Cisco IOS Software, 7200 Software (C7200P-SPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.4(24)T2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2009 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Mon 19-Oct-09 23:55 by prod_rel_team

ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 12.4(12.2r)T, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
BOOTLDR: Cisco IOS Software, 7200 Software (C7200P-BOOT-M), Version 15.2(4)S7, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc4)

YLINX-EDGE-LHE-01 uptime is 30 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System image file is "disk0:c7200p-spservicesk9-mz.124-24.T2.bin"
```

further

```
YLINX-EDGE-LHE-01#sh bootvar
BOOT variable =
CONFIG_FILE variable does not exist
BOOTLDR variable =
WARM_REBOOT variable = FALSE
Configuration register is 0x2102
........
```

here flash have both IOS can I delete the previous IOS from flash

```
YLINX-EDGE-LHE-01#show flash

-#- ED ----type---- --crc--- -seek-- nlen -length- ---------date/time--------- name
1   .. image        64588721  A152DC   27 10048092 Jan 24 2019 01:36:11 +00:00 c7200p-boot-mz.152-4.S7.bin
2   .. image        33A24A92 2DBF9C4   38 37398120 Jan 24 2019 01:44:20 +00:00 c7200p-adventerprisek9-mz.152-4.S7.bin

18089532 bytes available (47446468 bytes used)
```

Comment: You need to set the boot variable by using the following command in config mode: `boot system flash:c7200p-adventerprisek9-mz.152-4.S7.bin` **OR** `boot sytem bootdisk:c7200p-adventerprisek9-mz.152-4.S7.bin` - you can check with the bootvar command after setting it `show bootvar`.

Comment: Please let me know if it works, then i'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

Don't delete the IOS from the flash>

PLease share the output

`# show boot` -- check the NEW IOS is in the next reboot if not do below command.

```
conf t 
boot system flash:IOS image name.bin
```

Save the config

check the show boot